# how to customise the context menustrip in xtrascheduler in devxpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

hii

I am a fresher in devxpress now for my project i need to change the default context menu strip table(newappointment,new all day event etc)and need to add some other entries in the scheduler .help me please

Answer (score 0):

We've described how this can be done in the [How to: Customize the Context Menu](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2280) topic.

Comment: I tried tat one but its not working can u please tell what change s i have to make in the scheduler properties..please

Comment: I tried that one but its not working can u please tell what changes i have to make in the scheduler properties..please

Comment: You should subscribe to the PreparePopupMenu event of the XtraScheduler.  The code posted in the help topic is the event handler for this event.